# Memory used by java.awt.Image object

Tags: java, memory, profiling

How can I get the memory used by an instance of the class `java.awt.Image`?

There are [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52353/1196618), but is there an easier way of calculating the memory used by an object *of a specific class* (`java.awt.Image`)?

I would prefer to get the amount of bytes used programatically and not via a profiler so that I can use it to calculate memory statistics inside my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create about 1000 of them and see how much heap grows.  Do it a second time with a different image size and calculate the equation.  Should be roughly a linear equation -- `k1 + k2 * num_pixels` -- for a given color depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will vary between implementations of `java.awt.Image`, because it depends how the subclass decides to store the data.

But for BufferedImage, `img.getData().getDataBuffer();` will give you the raw DataBuffer that stores the image. You can then use `getDataType()` and `getSize()` to determine the capacity of the data buffer.